# Is there any way to install an Ethereum wallet on a Non-Google Android device?

Tags: wallets, android, mobile-wallet, jaxx

I have an Android device running Cyanogen Mod without Google services, but it seems all Android applications for Ethereum ship via Google Play only.

I kindly requested the Jaxx developers multiple times to provide alternate downloads, e.g. signed APKs or the F-Droid appstore, but [they refuse](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5057ey/jaxx_your_ethereum_wallet_and_interface/d71ovzo) to take a look into that issue.

Is there any way to install an Ethereum wallet on a Non-Google Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the [Yalp Store](https://fossdroid.com/a/yalp-store.html) which is available in F-Droid but allows to download Apps from Google Play.

You either sign in to Play using this app or you use the experimental anonymous downloader. It also keeps track of updates. This way I was able to get Jaxx wallet on my LineageOS device which is free from any Google services.

It's pretty convenient and I recently decided to [blog about it](https://dev.to/5chdn/aawwwgs-android-apps-which-work-without-google-services).

Answer (score 1):

1.Get a trusted friend/android emulator to install Jaxx on his device.
2. Tell him to install this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en to share the APK with you.

It is definitely not a secure way and can expose you to various attack vectors. But it will work.